# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What's the physics behind checking kicks?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/whats-the-physics-behind-checking-kicks)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it better to start out with a light weapon?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/is-it-better-to-start-out-with-a-light-weapon)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does it take to get a black belt in Taekwondo?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-it-take-to-get-a-black-belt-in-taekwondo)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Weapons in taekwondo?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/weapons-in-taekwondo)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Exercises for strengthening arms, wrists and fingers with the intent of sword use](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/exercises-for-strengthening-arms-wrists-and-fingers-with-the-intent-of-sword-us)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Good excercises to reduce the amount of pain in your palm/fingers when hitting with open palm?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/good-excercises-to-reduce-the-amount-of-pain-in-your-palm-fingers-when-hitting-w)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [The use and historical authenticity of a 9 hook broadsword](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/the-use-and-historical-authenticity-of-a-9-hook-broadsword)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I improve my technique in Judo?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/how-can-i-improve-my-technique-in-judo)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Taekwondo and muscle imbalance](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/taekwondo-and-muscle-imbalance)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to avoid Capoeira PCL strain](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2518/how-to-avoid-capoeira-pcl-strain)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---